# Google Contacts Fields to fill variables in email template

Tags: email, field, contacts, autofill

First of all, thank you for your time.

I have been looking for a while for a program, a script or anything that could help me automate a task that otherwise is going to take very long.
See, i'm a french computer technician working for almost exclusively doctors here in France.
The doctors receive results by email, the results are then imported to the patient's folder from the email automatically.
But in order for them to receive that information we have to communicate an email address from a special domain + the doctor's ID that is like your driver's ID.

We use google contact as an address book because it's convenient. Since whenever we make a new maintenance contract with a doctor we input everything to google contact the info is already there. Sometimes we have up to 20 doctors in the same cabinet to set.

[Link to a Google Sheet Contact Sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10vH4DfeBLbLPwu-F4xD7mjK06FQxymjjKHKRkjhjWlo/copy?copyComments=true)

The fields are the following :

Structure's Name : {{contact company name}} (all the doctors share the same structure)
Strutre's Adress : {{contact full address}} (all the doctors share the same structure)

1. First doctor

- Last Name : {{last_name}}
- First Name : {{first_name}}
- eMail Address : {{email_address}} (this one is tagged MSSANTE in ggC)
- Doc's ID : {{custom_field}} (this is a custom field tagged RPPS in ggC)

2. Second doctor

- Last Name : {{last_name}}
- First Name : {{first_name}}
- eMail Address : {{email_address}} (this one is tagged MSSANTE in ggC)
- Doc's ID : {{custom_field}} (this is a custom field tagged RPPS in ggC)

So on and so on.
Then this as to be sent to many laboratories all in BCC and the customers/doctors usually in CC

I was thinking of using google sheets or google's people API somehow...
Can someone give me a strategy or some code to start ?

Again thanks to anyone who can help even a bit.

Comment: access is denied to your spreadsheet, please make it readable! (I am french too)

Comment: Hi Mike, You should be able to make a copy of the SS with the link provided.
I have now allowed access to the original.
Thank you for you input.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the process. You want to send results by email, but what results? Where are they? and to whom? with CC to all doctors in the same practice? and with bcc to laboratories but where are they identified?

Comment: Mike,
Sorry to reply this late. The goal would be to send to the laboratories an email with the doctor's information so they could send the result to the doctors. They will use that info to ensure is the right doctor not an homonyme, and to configurate their software.
The mail looks as follow :

Lastname : STEELSON
First Name : Mike
Email Adresse (MSSanté) : steelson.mike@medecin.mssante.fr
RPPS : 1010010287

Comment: My answer was deleted ... pls review the new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function email() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const emails = ss.getSheetByName('LABS mails').getRange('C2:C').getValues().flat().filter(r => r != '').join(',')
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emails,
    subject: 'titre du mail',
    htmlBody: body()
  })
}
function body() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const template = ss.getSheetByName('Mail Template (Exemple)')
  const docteurs = ss.getSheetByName('Doctors')

  let [headers, ...data] = docteurs.getDataRange().getDisplayValues()
  let debut = template.getRange('A2:A').getValues().flat().filter(r => r != '').join('<br>')
  let variable = template.getRange('B2:B').getValues().flat().filter(r => r != '').join('<br>')
  let fin = template.getRange('C2:C').getValues().flat().filter(r => r != '').join('<br>')
  const liste = ['{CABINET}', '{NOM}', '{PRENOM}', '{EMAIL}', '{RPPS}']
  const colonnes = [1,4,3,8,7]

  let message = debut
  data.forEach((r, row) => {
    var texte = variable
    for (var i = 0; i < liste.length; i++) {
      texte = texte.replace(liste[i], r[+colonnes[i] - 1])
    }
    message += texte + '<br><br>'
  })
  message += fin

  return (message)
}
```

Put the text as follows (you will need a little html tags)

[image]

The email will be

[image]

Comment: For moderators, @JeanFrançoisFabre, please don't delete the answer, it has not already post elsewhere (this was a mistake and I have deleted it since this was not the right topic). Thx.